# Is this a valid TLS handshake

Tags: ssl, tcpdump

I am trying to validate a TLS version by establishing a connection with the server, below is the packet capture.

All I need to know is whether this means a connection was established or refused, and what would tell me that.
Many thanks.

```
'New TCP connection #1: 192.168.2.2(34318) <-> robot(443)\r\n'
 '1 1  0.0020 (0.0020)  C>S  Handshake\r\n'
 '      ClientHello\r\n'
 '        Version 3.3 \r\n'
 '        cipher suites\r\n'
 '        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384\r\n'

 '        ....more ciphers...

 '        TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV\r\n'
 '        compression methods\r\n'
 '                  NULL\r\n'
 '1    9.6362 (9.6341)  C>S  TCP FIN'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this information the client starts the TLS handshake by sending the ClientHello but does not get any response from the server - i.e. no reaction at all. The client then closes the connection after 9 seconds. This is not a valid (i.e. complete) TLS handshake.

Given that there had to be a successful TCP handshake before that (otherwise the client would not send the ClientHello) I suspect some deep packet inspection going on which allows the initial handshake but then drops the packets once it has more details about the contents of the connection.